# how to find whether a graph is tree or not?

Tags: algorithm, graph, depth-first-search

i am trying to solve a SPOJ problem [is it a tree ?](http://www.spoj.com/problems/PT07Y/) in which i have to check whether a graph is tree or not??
in this problem i am using DFS to detect whether the graph has cycle or not..

my code is..

```
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <deque>
#include <queue>
#include <stack>
#include <bitset>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <numeric>
#include <utility>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cctype>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <ctime>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

typedef long long int64;
typedef unsigned long long uint64;
#define two(X) (1<<(X))
#define twoL(X) (((int64)(1))<<(X))
#define contain(S,X) (((S)&two(X))!=0)
#define containL(S,X) (((S)&twoL(X))!=0)
const double pi=acos(-1.0);
const double eps=1e-11;
template<class T> inline void checkmin(T &a,T b){if(b<a) a=b;}
template<class T> inline void checkmax(T &a,T b){if(b>a) a=b;}
template<class T> inline T sqr(T x){return x*x;}
typedef pair<int,int> ipair;
#define SIZE(A) ((int)A.size())
#define LENGTH(A) ((int)A.length())
#define MP(A,B) make_pair(A,B)
#define PB(X) push_back(X)
int scanInt()
{
    char c;
    int ans=0;
    while(true)
    {
        c=getchar_unlocked();
        if(c==' ' || c=='\n')
            return ans;
        ans=(ans<<3)+(ans<<1)+c-'0';
    }
}
bool applyDFS(vector<vector<int> > &graph,int n)
{
    queue <int> st;
    int i,j=0;
    vector<bool> visited(n+1,false);
    int node=1;
    st.push(1);
    while(!st.empty())
    {
        node=st.front();
        st.pop();
        if(visited[node])
           {
            return false;
            }
            visited[node]=true;
        for(i=0;i<graph[node].size();i++)
            {
                if(!visited[graph[node][i]])
                    st.push(graph[node][i]);
            }
        j++;
    }
    return j==n?true:false;
}
int main()
{
    int n,m,x,y,i;
    //freopen("input.txt","r",stdin);
    n=scanInt();
    m=scanInt();
       vector <vector<int> > graph(n+1);
       stack <int > st;
    for(i=0;i<m;i++)
    {
          x=scanInt();
          y=scanInt();
          graph[x].PB(y);
          graph[y].PB(x);
          st.push(x);
    }
    if(applyDFS(graph,n))
        cout<<"YES\n";
    else
        cout<<"NO\n";
    return 0;
}
```

when i submit the solution i got a "time limit exceeded" message. Is there any better approach to solve this problem??

Comment: You don't need to try and find cycles. Think about the properties of a tree, most importantly, how many components does it have? And how many edges does it have?

Comment: @kevmo314 you can have a graph with 3 nodes and 2 edges that is *not* a tree (it contains a cycle). So it's definitely an "if" but not "only if"

Comment: @alfasin your graph has two components.

Comment: @alfasin well I wanted to avoid directly giving the answer away, but a tree is a graph that has one component and V-1 edges. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(graph_theory) namely "G is connected and has n − 1 edges."

Comment: @kevmo314 correct again, BUT, a forest (a collection of trees) is also a graph. So if to be strict, you can't avoid checking for cycles and connectivity.

Comment: @alfasin We're not looking for forests...?

Comment: @kevmo314 nope, he's looking for a special kind of forest with only one tree ;)

Comment: @alfasin yes, so a single component with V-1 edges is a sufficient condition for a single tree... if you can give me a counterexample of a graph with a single component and V-1 edges that is not a tree, I'll personally see that you get the next nobel prize.

Comment: @kevmo314 "single component" (connectivity) is an additional condition (to the |v|-1 edges). Both conditions together are indeed sufficient.

Comment: @alfasin "a tree is a graph that has one component and V-1 edges" ... that is literally what I said. /literally/.

Comment: Right, only now I see that you mentioned connectivity as well in your initial remark. I'm still glad I emphasized it though :)

Comment: @alfasin so next time you try to prove someone wrong, I recommend you try to be more to the point. otherwise it makes you seem silly. yes, it is more simple. checking connectivity is O(n) and checking edge count is O(1). n=20k, so that's way less than the time limit.

Comment: @kevmo314 hold your horses buddy. checking connectivity is *not* `O(n)` (assuming you meant `n` as the number of nodes)

Comment: @alfasin I'm just going to leave http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/Graph_Connectivity here and let my horses keep going.

Comment: @kevmo314 good! so now you said it yourself :) checking connectivity has the same complexity as DFS/BFS. And that **was** the point since my first comment: the OP already implemented the most efficient algorithm to validate a tree. Your suggestion that it can be done more efficiently - is simply wrong.

Comment: @alfasin the OP said he implemented it by finding cycles, which is not necessary and slower than just checking connectivity. additionally, it may have been your point, but not once did you say finding cycles was the most efficient. lastly, it's not the most efficient evidenced by the fact that the problem can be solved, and I have solved it doing exactly that: checking connectivity and counting edges. but feel free to believe it's wrong. again, I recommend you be more clear in what you're trying to get across in your comments. your point is lost in your vagueness and winky faces.

Comment: @kevmo314 being rude does not make you right. I didn't say that "finding cycles was the most efficient." only that your solution is not more efficient. If you think that your DFS/BFS to check connectivity is more efficient in time complexity than the BFS/DFS that checks for cycles, then we don't have a basis for additional discussion. Wish you all the best (sincerely - not sarcastically!).

Comment: @kevmo314 btw, I think that I see where you missed the point: checking connectivity is not O(n). Check the link to wiki that you posted above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mention by  kevmo314 in his comment, we need to check for both connectivity of the graph and the number of edges are exactly n-1 to make sure that the graph is a tree.

So there are two observations:

- We only need to check for connectivity if the number of edges is `n - 1`.
- Use [disjoint set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) for this problem, as every edge, if it is a tree, this edge should connect two disconnected components, otherwise, this graph is not a tree. So time complexity is O(n) as there are only `n - 1` edge to check.

Comment: -1 This algorithm will fail in the case I described in my first comment above. You cannot check connectivity in O(n).

Comment: @alfasin as I stated, we only need to check for connectivity if there is n - 1 edges, so O(n) will make it.

Comment: @alfasin why? Depth-First Search time complexity is O(V + E), in this case V = (E + 1) = n, so the time complexity is O(2*n) = O(n)? For Union Find with Path Compression it is ~ O(n).

Comment: @alfasin This algorithm does NOT fail. It's correct. The poster's answer is entirely relevant. The case you described above (disjoint graphs with cycles in some) will fail the connectivity test because there are n - 1 edges. And if there are more than n - 1 edges, then the connectivty test is not even required.

Comment: @wookie919 the most efficient "connectivity test" is BFS/DFS. There is nothing that Pham/Kevmo wrote that suggests a more efficient solution.

Comment: @alfasin so you agree with me on the O(n) thing? btw, I strongly believe that my algorithm will be faster than OP algorithm in most of the cases, as I added a check for the `n-1` edges, that is where the algorithm is improved, not on the connectivity part. Furthermore, for union-disjoint set, we only process each edge once, while in the question's algo, it will be processed twice!

Comment: @alfasin I never discussed efficiency. I simply corrected your comment, which was wrong. Pham's algorithm does not fail in the case that you described. Also connectivity can be chcked in O(n) when there are O(n) edges.

Comment: @wookie919 First, the OP asked specifically: "i got a time limit exceeded is there any better approach to solve this problem". This answer does NOT suggest a better approach. And second, Pham argues that in this case `o(n) = o(|e|+|v|)` which is correct in case of a Tree but it's just a "wissass" was to say - here, I can do it in the same complexity as the DFS above and make it look better. This answer does not suggest a "better approach" simply cause there is no "better approach". The OP has already implement an approach with an optimal complexity.

Comment: @alfasin. Both of your sentences in your first comment are still incorrect. 1. The algorithm does not fail in the case you described. 2. You can check connectivity in O(n) if m = O(n). I thought very hard about stopping right here. But you continue to claim incorrect things which I find problematic because it may be confusing people who are coming here to learn. Thus I will continue. OP's algorithm has the worst case time complexity of O(n^2), which occurs for dense graphs (m = O(n^2)). The algorithm given in this answer has the worst case time complexity of O(n). Thus, again, you are wrong.

Comment: @wookie919 assuming `n` to be the number of nodes, saying that you can check connectivity in O(n) is misleading since it's `O(|E|+|V|)` (which again, in this private case they have the same order of magnitude, but should not be worded as equals cause **this** will be confusing for the readers). Again, assuming that `n` is the number of nodes (or edges) you cannot check connectivity in O(n) since it requires you to go over *both* nodes and edges (again - in this private case it has the same complexity - but calling it o(n) is misleading - it should be called `O(|E|+|V|)`).

Comment: Second, the OP's implementation of DFS is fine, it will run in `O(|E|+|V|)` at worst case - not O(n^2) (what is `m` and `n` for you ?).

Comment: The reason I said it will not work is the suggestion that using a disjoint set will provide linear complexity. In a general graph this is not true. In the private case of tree it is - but then again - this is not any better than what the OP is already doing.

Comment: I think I understand what you're trying to say with "OP's algorithm has the worst case time complexity of O(n^2), which occurs for dense graphs (m = O(n^2)). " - this is false. ANY DFS will fail upon the first cycle it discovers which will be in... `O(|E|+|V|)` not `O(|E|^2)` or `O(|V|^2)` or whatever you mean by using `m`.

Comment: @alfasin. m is of course the number of edges, easily derived from the context. I said on a dense graph where m = O(n^2). It is common to denote |V| = n and |E| = m, as OP has done in his algorithm. The reason OP's algorithm is O(n^2) in the worst case is because he is reading all edges, instead of stopping when there are more than n - 1 edges. You have completely missed the point.

Comment: This is my final comment, now that the answer has (correctly) been accepted by the OP. I have no issues with admitting that I have lost a couple of reputation points by flagging some of your comments as obsolete and unconstructive. You have enough reputation points to have seen enough bad comments and answers for you to have a good understanding of when to stop and when to continue. It seems that in this particular question your ego got in the way. I hope the rest of your day is better. I mean it.

Comment: @wookie919 I see, you're saying that in this case (that the improvement is about not iterating more than |V|-1 edges) you're right! only now I see that Pham wrote it too but I missed it cause your comment followed his... This is indeed an improvement of potentially > `O(|V|)` removed my -1 and added +1

Comment: @wookie919 btw, I'm not sure why you flagged any of the comments. I appreciate the discussion and I like to be proved wrong - that's a good way to learn! thank you for not "giving up" on me  :)

Comment: @Pham trung i followed your approch but still get time limit exceeded

Comment: @pham Trung sorry i havnt seen that. I got my sollution accepted. actually i was still trying dfs but this time when the m=n-1 only then i use dfs to check connectivity but when i use dis joint set it is got accepted..

Comment: @Nitin9791 glad you are :)